# How to prevent eclipse from removing line breaks when formatting JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have this code :

```
section.append('<div class="thumbnail">' 
    + '<img src="public/images/thumb100x200.png">' 
         + '<span class="title">' + i + '</span>' 
    + '</div>');
```

When I format this code in eclipse it removes line breaks and the results becomes like this:

```
section.append('<div class="thumbnail">' + '<img src="public/images/thumb100x200.png">' + '<span class="title">' + i + '</span>' + '</div>');
```

How can I make eclipse not remove the line breaks when joining strings like this?

I have already looked for a setting under *Window->Preferences->Javascript->Editor*, but can't find anything that fixes this

Answer (score -6, accepted):

If you go to Window->Preferences->Javascript->Editor you will find all the autoformatting rules. Beyond that, good luck!

Comment: downvote because you don't mention which setting to look change

Comment: @tw_hoff A downvote means the answer was not helpful. The OP accepted this as the answer to his question, so by definition it was helpful to him.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work on 4.4.0

Project > Properties > Java Editor > Save Actions > Configure Workspace > Formatter > Edit > Line Wrapping > "Never join already wrapped lines".

Comment: And yet, this was exactly the setting I was looking for :)

Comment: This answer is for Java, not Script. Nevertheless: it works for the whole code in the project. If you want to prevent Eclipse from removing line breaks just for some sections, you can use the Off/On tags selective:

1. Go to [Window menu] > "Window" > "Preferences" > "Java" > "Code Style" > "Formatter" > Button "Edit ..." > section "Off/On Tags".
2. Set the checkbox there.
3. Add comments into your code like this:

        //@formatter:off
        System.
           out.
           println("Hello");
        //@formatter:on
4. Eclipse won't reformat the code between the comments.